# Winding number of a closed path

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, winding-number

I have to calculate the winding number of the curve |z|=3 around the point $\alpha=i$. After
parameterizing, the integral is as follows $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{3ie^{it}}{3e^{it}-i}dt$

After calculating the integral I get $\left[ ln(3e^{it}-i) \right]_0^{2\pi}$, but I get that it's equal to zero. I know the result of the integral should be $2\pi i$, but I don't know how to get there. I'm missing something but i don't know what.  Could you help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $\alpha = 0$, then the integral is trivial, but if $\alpha \neq 0$, then the integral is a multivalued $log$-function and you must use the Cauchy integral theorem to evaluate it.

Comment: There will be points on the contour where the logarithm is discontinuous. You can still evaluate the integral as
$$\int_{|z| = 3} \frac {dz} {z - i} =
\ln(z - i) \bigg\rvert_{z = -2 \sqrt 2 + i - i0}^{-2 \sqrt 2 + i + i0},$$
where $\ln$ is the principal branch.

Comment: @Maxim Consider extending your comment into an answer with detals, then we could upvote  :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** : Note that if $\gamma : [0,2\pi] \longmapsto \mathbb{C}$ where $\gamma(t) = Re^{it}, R > 0$ we have that :

If $|z| < R \Rightarrow I(\gamma,z) = 1$,

If $|z| > R \Rightarrow I(\gamma,z) = 0$

Where $I(\gamma,z)$ denotes the winding number of the curve around $z$.

Can you take it from here ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have $1/(2\pi i)\oint_\gamma1/(z-i)\rm dz=1$, by the Cauchy Integral Formula with $f(z)=1$.  This is as expected.